# Qt TableView remove strange boxes

Tags: c++, qt, windows-10-desktop

I want to use a QTableView. This is a result of some tests.

[image: TableView with 4 cells, every cell contains a misterious checkbox-like box]

As you can see, there are some boxes in every cell, before the content "123". What are these boxes and how can I remove these?

I think I need to change some properties of the QTableView, but I did not found a property related to these misterious boxes.
Here some code I used:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    //...

    TVLDataModel* model = new TVLDataModel();
    ui->uxTVLView->setModel(model);
}
```

TVLDataModel (inherits QAbstractTableModel)

```
int TVLDataModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 2;
}

int TVLDataModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 2;
}

QVariant TVLDataModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    return 123;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should change your `QVariant TVLDataModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const` function to indicate the role you are using. for example Qt::EditRole, Qt::BackgroundRole, etc.

for example :

```
QVariant TVLDataModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    switch(role){
       case Qt::EditRole :
       case Qt::DisplayRole :    
           return 123; 

       default : break;
    }
     return QVariant();
}
```

Otherwise you would return 123 for every ItemDataRole.

Comment: Yes exactly this is the issue. You are essentially returning (Qt::CheckState)123 for the Qt::CheckStateRole.

Answer (score 0):

Those "strange" boxes are checkboxes. Your model indicates that each item is checkable.